# Convert Array to Hash removing duplicate keys and adding values at the same time

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, enumerable

I have an array that looks like so:

```
f = [["Wed, 12-31", 120.0],["Thu, 01-01", 120.0], ["Thu, 01-01", 120.0]]
```

I can convert it to a hash and remove the duplicate keys:

```
h = Hash[ *f.collect { |v| [v] }.flatten ]
# => {"Wed, 12-31"=>120.0, "Thu, 01-01"=>120.0}
```

which is almost there, but I'd like to sum the value for elements with the identical date strings, the desired result from the above array would be this:

```
{"Wed, 12-31"=>120.0, "Thu, 01-01"=>240.0}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Note, you can convert your array to a hash discarding duplicate keys without the `.collect.flatten` nonsense. Just use `Hash[array]`. `f.collect { |v| [v] }` is just mapping the array **to itself**. It doesn't *do* anything. `.flatten` on an already flat array is equally useless.

Comment: @KennyMeyer err, google? https://www.google.ca/search?q=ruby+enumerable+documentation&oq=ruby+enumerable+documentation&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64l2.3818j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Thanks for the tip on ```.collect``` and ```.flatten```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
result = Hash.new(0)
f = [["Wed, 12-31", 120.0],["Thu, 01-01", 120.0], ["Thu, 01-01", 120.0]]
f.each { |subarray| result[subarray[0]] += subarray[1] }
puts result
```

If you would like to be fancy you could use `.inject()`

Comment: If you'd like to be fancier, and lazier, use `each_with_object` instead of `inject`. It works more cleanly.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [`each_with_object`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
ary = [["Wed, 12-31", 120.0], ["Thu, 01-01", 120.0], ["Thu, 01-01", 120.0]]

hash = ary.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)){ |(k,v), h| h[k] += v }
=> {"Wed, 12-31"=>120.0, "Thu, 01-01"=>240.0}
```

Comment: I would just like to add that while I accepted @kennymeyer's answer, I later switched to this solution.

Comment: Just to reiterate something you'll see occasionally on Stack Overflow: Don't pick the first answer that comes along and answers your question. There are many ways to do something, and people aren't poised at their computers waiting to pounce on questions. Answers sometimes take a while to formulate; I often wait to answer hoping someone will respond with what I consider to be the right way to do something, and then later will add mine if nobody has done it or answered as thoroughly as I think the answer should be. So, ask, then wait a day and see what shows up.

Answer (score 2):

The other standard approach to this type of problem is to use [Enumerable#group_by](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by):

```
Hash[ary.group_by(&:first).map { |d,a| [d, a.reduce(0) { |t,(_,n)| t+n }] }]
  #=> {"Wed, 12-31"=>120.0, "Thu, 01-01"=>240.0}
```

We have:

```
a = ary.group_by(&:first)
  #=> {"Wed, 12-31"=>[["Wed, 12-31", 120.0]],
  #    "Thu, 01-01"=>[["Thu, 01-01", 120.0], ["Thu, 01-01", 120.0]]} 
b = a.map { |d,a| [d, a.reduce(0) { |t,(_,n)| t+n }] }
  #=> [["Wed, 12-31", 120.0], ["Thu, 01-01", 240.0]] 
Hash[b] 
  #=> {"Wed, 12-31"=>120.0, "Thu, 01-01"=>240.0}
```

or with Ruby 2.0+:

```
b.to_h
  #=> {"Wed, 12-31"=>120.0, "Thu, 01-01"=>240.0}
```

A variant of this is:

```
ary.group_by(&:first).map { |d,a| [d, a.transpose.last.reduce(:+) ] }.to_h
```

Comment: Thanks for Ruby's 2.0+ `to_h` approach! That's rad.